# Nodejs + Solution for [wit] [converse] Error: Model not found (404) in 2017?

Tags: node.js, facebook-messenger-bot, wit.ai

I'm try to run node-wit/messenger.js and get error:

> [wit] [converse] Error: Model not found (404)

Google tells me I must create a story for the bot.

But it was solved in 2016. For now, WIT notification Stories and POST /converse have been deprecated. This will break in February 2018!

So, anyone can help me to pass it please? Any solution for this problem in 2017?

Ps: I'm trying use 'context' in GET /message to save the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use wit.ai then you need to create your intent and then use the API directly to extract it.

```
const client = new WIT({accessToken: <WIT_API_TOKEN>});
client.message(message, context)
.then((body) => {

})
.catch(console.error);
```

You need to parse the content of 'body'. This will contain the intent and your entities.

Your Bot will then need to handle the different replies based on what was parsed.